# One message got stuck on one of the queue on Solace

Tags: solace

In one of the queue in solace, one message got stuck and rest of the message has consumed, please help me to troubleshooting this

Comment: Can we have the following output via the CLI? "show queue <queue_name> message-vpn <vpn_name> detail" and "show queue <queue_name> message-vpn <vpn_name> stats detail"

Answer (score 0):

One common possibility is that the Solace appliance/VMR has already delivered the message to a consumer, and the consumer has failed to acknowledge the message. Therefore, the Solace appliance/VMR can no longer deliver the message to another consumer unless the consumer acknowledges the message, or disconnects it's flow.

The "show queue  message-vpn  detail" would help identify whether this is so.

```
solace1> show queue q1 message-vpn default detail

Name                                 : q1
Message VPN                          : default
Durability                           : Durable
Id                                   : 3813
Type                                 : Primary
Admin Ingress                        : Up
Admin Egress                         : Up
Access Type                          : Non-Exclusive
Owner                                :
Created by mgmt                      : Yes
All Others Permission                : Delete (1111)
Quota (MB)                           : 700000
Respect TTL                          : No
Reject Msg to Sender on Discard      : Yes
Bind Time Forwarding Mode            : Store-And-Forward
Current Messages Spooled             : 1
Current Spool Usage (MB)             : 0.0001
High Water Mark (MB)                 : 0.0006
Total Delivered Unacked Msgs         : 1  <=================== 1 Message has been delivered to an application but is unacknowledged.
Max Delivered Unacked Msgs Per Flow  : 10000
Total Acknowledgments In-Progress    : 0
Max Redelivery                       : 1
Consumer Ack Propagation             : Yes
Reject Low-Priority-Msg              : No
Reject Low-Priority-Msg Limit        : 0
Low-Priority-Msg Congestion State    : Disabled
Oldest Msg Id in Spool               : 457000639
Newest Msg Id in Spool               : 457000639
Max Msg Size Allowed (B)             : 10000000
Bind Count                           : 1
Max Bind Count                       : 1000
Topic Subscription Count             : 2
Network Topic                        : #P2P/QUE/q1
Egress Selector Present              : No

Event Threshold                           Set Value      Clear Value
---------------------------------- ---------------- ----------------
Bind count                                 80%(800)         60%(600)
Spool usage (MB)                        80%(560000)      60%(420000)
Reject Low-Priority-Msg Limit                80%(0)           60%(0)

Egress Flows

  Client Name                        : perfhost/6588/#000b0001
    Flow Status                      : Active-Consumer
    Deliver From                     : input stream
    Status Updates                   : Not Requested
    No Local Delivery                : No
    Request Redelivery               : No
    Selector                         :
    Window Size                      : 255
    Last Connect Time                : 2016-01-05 13:51:44 SGT
    Activation Time                  : 2016-01-05 13:51:44 SGT
    Flow Id                          : 4191
    Last Msg Id Delivered            : 457000639
```

Comment: It's three years later, but I'm going to take a shot:  assume that I had an incidence of stuck messages, but that the process downstream was bounced before any analysis like you suggest could be performed.   Is there anything else that can be done post-mortem?    Also, when you say "one common possibility", that implies there are others - what else can cause stuck messages?